# Chrome redirects to Messenger on Samsung mobile

Tags: samsung, chrome-for-android, facebook-messenger

I have been getting redirect notices on my Samsung Google Chrome browser with a link to Messenger, e.g. here is the last link: `https://www.google.com/url?q=chrome-native://recent-tabs/&usg=AFQjCNGr_fE_CEo3dlMRGaW3TnfE3S3U6Q`.

I once installed Messenger, but I have never used it nor do I even have a Facebook account. But now it makes it appear like I am using Play Store secretly, using Messenger, and my spouse believes I am secretly using Messenger.

How can I stop the redirection?

Comment: Please tell some more things. That every when you click chrome browser it directly redirect you to messenger or while browsing other things in between browsing you see redirection to another link ? And try any other browser like 'Samsung Internet' and see if the problem still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these steps:

- Clear Cache, Cookies, and Data of Chrome.
- Also Clear the downloaded data if there are any infected files.
- Check any previously installed apps causing troubles, if any, try uninstalling them.
- Scan using any good antivirus app or a built-in one.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when I use Facebook on the browser and it redirects me to open Messenger even if I don't want to, but I finally got the solution:

1. If you're having Messenger already downloaded, then uninstall it.  And reinstall it again.
2. Log in to your Messenger after the download but don't allow the permissions to access your contacts or media.
3. Keep it aside and go to your mobile settings.
4. Go to app manager
5. Click on Messenger.
6. It will show some options like permissions, notifications, open by default, etc.
7. Click on open by default.
8. It will give two options or more: click on open supported links in an app.
9. Click on disallow option.

But make sure that the Messenger you have is recently downloaded.

Comment: Quoting OP: "I once installed messenger but I have never used it nor do I even have a Facebook account." So step 2 would fail.

Comment: Step 2 is irrelevant anyway.  This should work.